# Flutter - Background function

Tags: flutter, notifications, alert, alarm, background-task

I built an app in flutter to set some alerts on stocks prices. So I fetch the stock’s data from yahoo finance and then compare it to a target price every 30 seconds and send a notification when the actual price is below the target. As I was expecting, as soon as I kill the app, the function stop running. How could my function runs even if the app is close? Do I need to use some cloud function or something else ?

Comment: flutter background tasks [here][1]


  [1]: https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124